# Octave returning the get_forge_pkg could not read URL error

Tags: windows, octave

Following [this question](https://discordapp.com/channels/384316553497280512/723625266261393488/918378983526113281) on Octave's Discord channel, I tried to install the `control` package with

```
pkg install -forge control
```

but I get the error message

```
error: get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection
error: called from
get_forge_pkg at line 72 column 7
get_forge_download at line 32 column 14
pkg at line 500 column 31
```

looking at the [content](https://fossies.org/linux/octave/scripts/pkg/private/get_forge_pkg.m) of the `get_forge_pkg.m` script, all URLs are available within my network. I know how to download the [package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/index.html) and [install it manually](https://wiki.octave.org/Category:Octave_Forge), but I want to understand the problem and fix it in a canonical way.

**P.S.1.** This post is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179187/can-not-install-image-acquisition-package-in-octave), as the other page is Linux/Ubuntu/Snap specific.

**P.S.2.** strangely enough, trying to install the package manually using `pkg install <packageName.tar.gz>` I get the error:

```
warning: creating installation directory C:\Users\foobar~1\octave
warning: called from
    install at line 36 column 5
    pkg at line 568 column 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 72 there is this line downloading the package list, not the package itself.

```
    [html, succ] = urlread ("https://packages.octave.org/list_packages.php");
```

Works for me in a Chrome browser, but that redirects to `https://octave.sourceforge.io/list_packages.php`. Let's see what happens with curl:

```
[tmp] $ curl https://packages.octave.org/list_packages.php
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.
[tmp] $
```

Looks like an expired SSL certificate on Octave's website. Please report this to the Octave maintainers at https://octave.discourse.group/.

Comment: Then the other problem with the manual installation must be something different, right?

Comment: Yes, that appears totally unrelated. Maybe something to do with Windows's handling of long file names. Either the output snippet with warnings you posted is incomplete, or `pkg`'s output is somewhat lacking there, or maybe it actually worked! A warning is just a warning, not an outright error, and doesn't mean the overall operation failed. Try running `pkg load control` and see if it works even though there were warnings during the installation.